# libpcap/tcpdump Why does an empty filter capture less that a "tcp" filter

Tags: tcpdump, libpcap

I was looking for libpcap and filter behaviour. 
I found I strange behavior:
Why does an empty filter capture less packets than a "TCP" filter?

Comment: You should show the output of pcap in these scenarios. It will report packets received, packets filtered, and so on. Make sure neither outputs are 0 bytes, as well, as this might point at a known bug in pcap. Finally,  this might be a case of non-filtered captures overrunning the network device, which is why inspecting the output is helpful.

Comment: Here's a related answer that has some good details on how to determine what pcap is doing: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29369/156990